# Update query that will update a column that is generated recursivley

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a table that contains categories in a hierarchal way.

The path column is currently empty but should look like the following:

```
id  parent_id  name   path

1   (null)     vehicles   '/vehicles'
2   1          honda      '/vehicles/honda'
3   1          toyota     '/vehicles/toyota'
4   2          civic      '/vehicles/honda/civic'
5   4          dx         '/vehicles/honda/civic/dx'
6   (null)     airplans   '/airplanes'
7   3          camry      '/vehicles/toyota/camry'
```

How can I write an update query for this table that will update the 'path' column?

Note:  This is a single query that will update the path column for all the rows, and the path is a hierarchal in nature so this I'm sure requires recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with recursive cat_tree (id, parent_id, name, full_path) as (
   select id,parent_id,name, '/'||name as full_path
   from categories
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id,c.parent_id,c.name,p.full_path||'/'||c.name
   from categories c
     join cat_tree p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
update categories
  set path = c.full_path
from cat_tree c 
  where c.id = categories.id;
```

Depending on how you use this, you might want to think about getting rid of the column `path` altogether and create a view based on the recursive CTE.

Comment: That works great, if you don't mind can you explain the magic behind it please?    I'd rather have this done as a single operation that on a per-request basis which I think a view would entail.

Comment: @Blankman: the first part (the `with` part) is called a common table expression and recursively queries the table. Details are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html the result of that is then used to run the update statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think a simple mysql update query will handle the thing .
Try this : 
`UPDATE '$TABLE_NAME' SET PATH = '$VALUE' WHERE id= '$id';`

Comment: looks like he's in postgres

Comment: The update query has to update the paths of all the rows by itself.  I'm not looking for a simple update query here - this is complicated and requires some recursion I'm sure.